# tomcat is responding The requested resource is not available

Tags: spring-boot, war, tomcat10

I have installed tomcat 10.1.8 when i put my war file inside webapps i get "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

[image]

am new for tomcat so i have no idea what to do with it

Comment: There is far too little information here. Include at least some of the framework versions you are using, how are you building the war etc.

Comment: spring boot 2.7.5 [clean,install]

Comment: Which is your problem, that doesn't work with Tomcat 10 or higher, Tomcat 8 or 9 is what you need (or use Spring Boot 3.0 or 3.1 which works with Tomcat 10 or higher).